# Usei o createElement pra criar um botao a partir de um onclick em outro botao, mas ele cria outro elemento sempre, como limitar isso?

Tags: javascript, funções, button, elementos, create

Eu quero criar um botao a partir de um botao inicial, para isso usei o createElement:

```js
function calcular() {
    var resu = document.body
    var agd = document.createElement('button')
    var agendar = document.createTextNode('AGENDAR CONSULTA INICIAL')
    agd.appendChild(agendar)
    resu.appendChild(agd)
    }
```

```html
 <td>
               <button id="botao" onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
            </td>
      
            <h1>O calculo feito pela calculadora não considera a variação do dolar,</h1>
            <h1> apenas te dá uma média de acordo com as informações encontradas na internet e no nosso sistema.</h1>
            <div id="resultado">
                <h2 id="msg"></h2>
                <h2 id="valor"></h2>
                <h2 id="mensal"></h2>
                <div id="frasco"></div>
                <div id="btn"></div>
            </div>
```

porem sempre que eu clico no botao ele cria uma nova caixa, como limitar isso para aparecer apenas uma vez? não encontrei resposta em perguntas semelhantes, nem achei a documentação correta.

Comment: oculta o primeiro botão! ou desabilite o botão!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function calcular() {
  if (document.getElementById('btn-agendar')) {
    return;
  }
  var resu = document.body
  var agd = document.createElement('button')
  var agendar = document.createTextNode('AGENDAR CONSULTA INICIAL')
  agd.id = 'btn-agendar'
  agd.appendChild(agendar)
  resu.appendChild(agd)
}
```

```html
<td>
  <button id="botao" onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
</td>

<h1>O calculo feito pela calculadora não considera a variação do dolar,</h1>
<h1> apenas te dá uma média de acordo com as informações encontradas na internet e no nosso sistema.</h1>
<div id="resultado">
  <h2 id="msg"></h2>
  <h2 id="valor"></h2>
  <h2 id="mensal"></h2>
  <div id="frasco"></div>
  <div id="btn"></div>
</div>
```

Você pode criar um id para o botão na primeira vez que ele for criado e antes de tudo criar um if verificando se no documento já existe algum elemento com aquele id, caso exista vai retornar vazio.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Lucas, acabei mudando um detalhe ou outro, mas ajudou muito, Grato!

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha conseguido, sucesso :)